# Laravel remove backslashes from JSON response in Restful API

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, laravel-5

I'm building a restful api and i'm trying to pass image URL that stored in database

for example, when i'm trying to pass this link to api `127.0.0.1:8000/images/123.jpg` it appearances like `127.0.0.1:8000\/images\/123.jpg`

i tried things like `stripslashes()` but nothing works

Controller

```
public function companiesAll()
{
    $companies = Company::where('status',1)->select('id', 'name',"image")->get();

        return response()->json([$companies]);
}
```

Comment: You need to parse the `JSON` on `front-end` that would auto strip those slashes

Comment: @BasheerKharoti give me an example please

Comment: Update your code and include where you call the API (Ajax request)

Comment: @BasheerKharoti Dude this is a Restful API for mobile app!

Comment: Whatever API it is, you will be consuming it somewhere

Comment: There is no need to escape backslashes. When you decode the JSON on the client-side or server-side, backslashes will be auto stripped. No need to worry about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
return response()->json($companies, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```